# Setting a custom AuthenticationDetailsSource on the Spring Oauth2 Token Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We need to set a custom AuthenticationDetailsSource onto the spring OAuth2 /token endpoint to capture some custom headers which our clients must supply.

The security for that endpoint appears to be configured in org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer and I can't see a way of overriding it.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "fluent" api for adding authentication details to the client authentication (assuming that's what you mean). You can easily take control of the token endpoint security though if you ditch `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and just extend `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration` directly. Then you can add your own security configuration in the normal Spring Security way with a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.